# How to Disable Button after first Click in android

Tags: java, android

I am using this code but its not working i am still able to click more than 2 times.

```
accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        accept.setEnabled(false);
                        if (dialog1 != null && dialog1.isShowing()) {
                            dialog1.dismiss();
                        }
                        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                    }
                });
```

its not showing any error but not working as desired.

Comment: Have you tried setting `accept.setClickable(false);`, too? Is the button a plain `Button` or something enhanced like an `ImageButton`?

Comment: Is the `accept` button in the dialog or in the activity/fragment?

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean run = true;
accept.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(run) {
            run = false;
            //your code
        }
    }
});
```